# How to define a Where query with 2 conditions, with QueryBuilder in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, query-builder

I have this statement: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='12' AND fname ='aaa';`

How i use the same statement in QueryBuilder like:

```
Statement statement = QueryBuilder.select().all().from("users").where(eq("id", 12)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Statement statement = QueryBuilder.select().all().from("users").where(eq("id", 12)).and(eq("fname", "aaa"));
```

Haven't tried myself though :)